# Java: Splitting a large unit test class

Tags: java, design, unit-testing, testing

The project (Java/Spring) I currently work on has a rather large unit-test class for one of its services : more than 1000 lines, several `Nested class` (one per big functionality), some tests without a `Nested class`, ...

Finding this file rather difficult to read, and to manage (a modification in the service, and you have to take time to find the corrects tests to fix/update), I proposed to split the class to have one test file per Nested Class, each one linked to a "principal" test file, which will be managing the Mock & the tests without Nested Class. All the tests files would be put into a specific package.

I am wondering if this would be a good thing to do? or if it was something to avoid to do ?

I hope i was clear enough.
Have a nice day

Comment: Anecdotally, I'd say that your nested classes are the problem, not the unit test class.  But the principle behind your proposal is sound.  Gary Bernhardt (of "Destroy All Software" fame) calls it the "Squish Principle,"  which basically means "smaller classes make better architecture."

Comment: Yeah - because you have unit tests for the service, you should be able to decompose the service itself into something more manageable. You may be able to do this with relative ease, or you may need to do it step by step if the tests know too much about the internals, but either way, the tests are a safety net. As you decompose the service, the tests class should split as well.

Comment: Ask your team, if necessary. If you can decide alone, try it out. If a 1000 lines file is hard or easy to handle, and if several files are simpler to manage, depends a lot on your development environment / IDE.

Comment: @DocBrown: Are you suggesting "code folding?" Because I can point you to a whole bunch of people that are adamantly against the use of #region.  Not saying I agree with them, just sayin'.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: no, I am not suggesting any special feature. But I am pretty sure some Java IDEs will allow to list or navigate between nested classes (or methods of those classes) in a single file better than others. What I am suggesting is talking to the team, and trying out what works best in the OPs environment.

Comment: We don't have any specific IDE. Some use VisualCode, other (like me) IntelliJ. I am not familiar with "code folding" and "Squish principle", I will look into it. I asked the team about the splitting, some find it's a good idea, other are saying it's not a good design...

Answer (score 8):

I do not care about the nested classes. I care about being forced to look at things that don’t matter. Tell me one story at a time.

The whole point of not putting all the code in one file is that the stuff I have to think about now is in one place and stuff I don’t need to see now hides in some other file.  Oh sure, you can mash it all into one file and watch it grow but just because it still compiles doesn’t mean that’s a good idea.

Organize code for humans. We like short, pointed stories about few subjects. Not thousand line odyssey’s about every possible thing that can be crammed into this particular file.

But, before I let you break up that file you have to solve one of the hardest problems in computer science: you have to think of good names.

You can cause an even bigger mess by breaking this up with poor names. Names are how I find this stuff. Give me good names, names that don’t surprise me when I look inside, names that help me find what I’m looking for. You can break it up as finely as the compiler will let you. Because I just need the parts of the story that matter to me. I don’t need every [also-ran](https://www.google.com/search?q=also+ran).

Pay some heed to the current organization of the code, of course. Using a better style won’t shine if it drastically clashes with the current style. How you feel while breaking up the code isn’t important. It’s how you’re making the next poor coder feel.

So talk with your team. Tell them the names you have in mind. Show them how it would look. See what they think.  Be sure the pain you save them from is worse than the pain you cause.

Comment: This is precisely the problem we're having with a bit of code one of our coworkers wrote before they retired.  It has methods with thousands of lines in them.  I don't need to see all that.  This is where the "squish principle" comes in; refactor all that into separate methods, and you don't have to look at the whole thing at once anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in my experience the single greatest limiting factor of code organization is vocabulary. Breaking down code requires good names. Thinking of and testing good names is real work. Ignoring this always makes a mess.

Comment: Sure, but limiting the *scope* of the code you have to look at at one time greatly moderates that problem, even if you have bad names.  I can always fix the names; the IDE even helps me to do that.  Refactoring a big method is a bit harder.

Comment: @RobertHarvey oh no. Bad names create leaky abstractions. No one knows what belongs in what. Soon you’re jumping through file after file wishing everything was in one file.  There is no substitute for a good name.

Comment: If only we could make names that actually accomplish that.  Fortunately, there are always comments.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like a good name as much as the next person.  But it's an art form, and many software developers are not good at it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well now I think you’re just messing with me.

Comment: Put it this way.  I've come to rely on the principle that most developers don't have the skills that I do.  Which is bad, because my skills aren't all that good to begin with.  So if I want my code to be maintainable by the next person, the solution is not good names; it is making my code *dead simple.*

Comment: Basically, Uncle Bob Clean Code simple.

Comment: @RobertHarvey dead simple with bad names means hours finding the dead simple one line of code that needs fixing. Good names make it dead simple to find dead simple code.

Comment: Which is why I don't rely on the names, unless I'm familiar with the code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I’ll give you a dead simple test for a good name: looking inside doesn’t surprise anyone. It makes clear what does and doesn’t belong inside.

Comment: Of course.  If only we had those kinds of names in abundance.  You said it yourself; *naming is hard.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey that’s why you talk to you team. Naming things isn’t something you have to do alone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey & candied_orange: from what I gathered, people often get told to "follow established conventions and project structure & best practices", which is, on the face of it, fine, but due to lack of context (perhaps because of lack of communication), combined with lack of design skills, in practice this too often translates into (1) applying "best practices" religiously, and (2) emulation, via copy & alter, of existing code, resulting in duplication of what could be extracted into a separate abstraction (an organizing object of some sort, a helper class, whatever). 1/2

Comment: After all, they are just following "established principles". And then it all gets tangled up because the abstraction is implicit and has no clear interface; the code just grows, and you see things like comments denoting entire sections (or #region-s). Now, names do help when it comes to organization, but the problem is that names are not just about defining buckets that tell people where to put stuff. Names are not enough - people have to understand what those names *represent* (the concepts behind them). 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović which is why you run names by other people before you set them in stone. Names like Foo and miscellaneous represent concepts. They just don’t happen to be concepts that help organize code.

Comment: @candied_orange - yes, I agree. But my point is, people often *don't* even introduce new names (or concepts) because they can't see when to break the existing patterns (or it doesn't even occur to them that they should do so at some point). They just keep doing the same thing over and over. Bad code comes into being very systematically.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović true. We should all be deeply suspicious of code. Existing code has inertia. It strongly favors code monkey see, code monkey do. Even when code monkey knows better.

Comment: About the naming, the test class will be split by nested classes, each one being already named from a method inside the service. Example : the method `updateEntity` has a nested class named `updateEntityTest`, which will become its own class inside the file `UpdateEntityTest`. There is not reinvention, but I agree that correctly naming class/method/etc can be difficult

Comment: @Baerrow Why does your example put test code within the same file as production code? Anyway, the test class is also split by methods. A nested class is just another structure within the file. A bad name means I have to keep jumping around to inspect and reinspect the contents of that structure. A good name says it all.

Comment: @candied_orange `updateEntity()` is in the file `EntityService`, linked to a test file `EntityServiceTest` which contains nested class, one per "big" functions of the service. I hope is clearer ^^

Comment: @Baerrow nope. I'm still lost. When I code the linking goes the other way. Production code doesn't know about test code.

Comment: @candied_orange when i say "linked" it's like this `@InjectMocks private EntityService entityService;` inside the test class.

Comment: Production code that knows it's being tested is weird and wrong to me. Anyway, if that's what you're doing consider [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html): "In the above example the field ArticleManager annotated with @InjectMocks can have a parameterized constructor only or a no-arg constructor only, or both. All these constructors can be package protected, protected or private, however Mockito cannot instantiate inner classes, local classes, abstract classes and of course interfaces. Beware of private nested static classes too."